# Static pages with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a wordpress site that is a store front/e-commerce site. I have the theme developed and working fine, but I need to have a few pages with forms that would be static (as in, I don't need to use plugins or have posts on these pages). What is the best way to do this? I have the static pages developed, is there a way to just upload them and use them as is?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the "Page" section of WordPress?

Answer (score -2):

If the layout of the static pages is similar to your template (which I believe would be the case because they are a part of the same website), then just create a new page through your admin panel. You can copy and paste the relevent HTML into the wysiwyg editor: do remove the header and the footer code.

Alternatively, you could upload the static HTML pages in the root directory of WordPress. This could require you to add an additional rule in your .htaccess file and therefore is not the best approach.